# Unusual method appeared when decompiling JAR file into java project

Tags: java, jar, jd-gui

When attempting to decompile a JAR file into a Java project using the Java Decompiler JD-GUI, I encountered an issue with the decompiled methods. Here is an example:

```
public Node getNode() {
    Node res = null;
    try {
      Exception exception2, exception1 = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return res;
}
```

**I'm seeking assistance in two aspects:**

1. How can I resolve the apparent issue with the Exception exception2, exception1 = null; try/catch block, as the original method should contain different code?
2. Are there alternative methods available that are more efficient for decompiling JAR files into Java projects and executing them?

Comment: Re 2.: Yes, there are. Do not decompile external dependencies, but reference the jar as a library. If a library does not come with source code, you are probably not allowed to decompile the jar anyways. Case in point, your sample code looks like it was decompiled from a flow-obfuscated class file which means the jar was intentionally modified to prevent decompilation.

Comment: Re 1: How do you know what the "original method" should contain? There's zero context in the question so it's impossible to know if it makes sense or not--it could be an obfuscated parent class method that's **supposed** to return `null` for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to note about decompiling ...

Some libraries, like the CyberArk libraries, are intentionally coded in such a way that makes them hard to understand.

Also, if the library is compiled from a language other than Java, you will not get what you expect. This is particularly true with Groovy, where a bunch of `sitecall` commands appear.